# Could Robust Subspace Clustering be used to remove outliers?

Tags: clustering, data-mining, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I have two samples set, one is positive, and the other is negative. But, in each of both sets, there are some outliers that don't belong to it. Can the Robust subspace clustering be used to  help me refine the two datasets and remove the outliers. I just want those most probable samples to be left. Maybe the Mixture of Gaussian could do this thing. In this task, what are the differences between RSC ang GMM? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist subspace outlier detection methods, too. For example SOD and COP:

> H.-P. Kriegel, P. Kröger, E. Schubert, A. Zimek
>   **Outlier Detection in Axis-Parallel Subspaces of High Dimensional Data**
>   In: Proceedings of the 13th Pacific-Asia Conference on Knowledge Discovery and Data Mining (PAKDD), Bangkok, Thailand, 2009
>
> Hans-Peter Kriegel, Peer Kröger, Erich Schubert, Arthur Zimek
>   **Outlier Detection in Arbitrarily Oriented Subspaces**
>   In: Proc. IEEE International Conference on Data Mining (ICDM 2012)

Both are available in [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/), which is where I've learned about them.